# How to send InfluxDB tags with Riemann client dynamically

Tags: clojure, influxdb, riemann

Is it possible to send influx db tags dynamically, the following configuration seems to not working because when I'm trying to select all the tags via influx db client, it returns 0 results, please advice how it's supposed to be changed. Thanks in advance.

```
(def send-influx
(influxdb/influxdb {
    :host "localhost"
    :db "riemann"
    :username "riemann"
    :password "riemann"}
 ))

(streams
(where (and (not (expired? event)) (service "service"))
    #(info %)
    (by [:host :service :id]
        (changed :metric {:pairs? true}
            (fn [[startEvent endEvent]]
                (when-not (empty? startEvent)
                    (let [diff (- (:metric endEvent) (:metric startEvent))]
                        (send-influx [{
                            :host (:host startEvent),
                            :service (:service startEvent),
                            :id (:id startEvent),
                            :metric diff,
                            :time (:time startEvent) },
                            :tag-fields {:id (:id startEvent)} }]  
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
))
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it doesn't help a lot, because for some reasons there were some parse exceptions due to versions incompatibility or smth, however I eventually was able to make it work by changing the configs to the following

```
    (def send-influx
    (influxdb/influxdb {
        :host "localhost"
        :db "riemann"
        :username "riemann"
        :password "riemann"
        :tag-fields #(:id)})

(streams
(where (and (not (expired? event)) (service "service"))
    #(info %)
    (by [:host :service :id]
    (changed :metric {:pairs? true}
        (fn [[startEvent endEvent]]
            (when-not (empty? startEvent)
                (let [diff (- (:metric endEvent) (:metric startEvent))]
                    (send-influx [{
                        :host (:host startEvent),
                        :service (:service startEvent),
                        :id (:id startEvent),
                        :metric diff,
                        :time (:time startEvent) },
                        :id (:id startEvent) }]  
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from the Riemann documentation:

```
(def influx (influxdb {:host "localhost"
                       :db "riemann"
                       :version :new-stream}))

(streams
  (smap
    (fn [event]
      (assoc event :measurement     (:service event)
                   :influxdb-tags   {:state (:state event)}
                   ;; :value = 0 by default
                   :influxdb-fields {:value (or (:metric event) 0)}))
    influx))
```

As you can see, you should use :measurements, :influxdb-tags, and :influxdb-fields keys in events.

This configuration should works with Riemann 0.2.13 or higher.

Comment: "should" but doesn't